# Copy Constructor and Overloaded Assignment?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

Can anybody explain me Assignment Operator in below mention code. I have

**Ques 1**: Why that assignment operator return Reference Object [I know this is used for something like this `c1 = c2 = c3`, But how this is work]

**Quest 2**: I have created dynamic pointer `tempName` but I've not  release the memory, so there is a memory leak. How I can resolve that. Or give me example if you have.

**Quest 3**: I have assigned `tempName` in name, so name is pointing to `tempName` if I delete `tempName` before the return, then what will happen.

```
Contact& operator=( const Contact& rhs ) {
  char* tempName = new char[ strlen( rhs. name ) + 1] ;
  delete[ ] name;
  name = tempName;
  strcpy( name, rhs. name ) ;
  age = rhs. age;
  return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Q1.

When you return a reference to an object, then you have the ability to put it in the left side of an assignment to assign another value. So, I see two reasons for it.

(1) Avoid an unnecessary copy.

(2) Default behaviour of assignment in C++, you can do

```
a = (b = c)
```

or

```
(a = b) = c
```

The first form is OK even with returning the value. **But** for the second one, you must return a reference to the value to have a behaviour as same as normal C++ assignments.<sup>†</sup>

### Q2.

Yes, it has memory leak. Unless, you delete the `name` in the destructor.

### Q3.

`name` and `tempName` are pointing to the same address. So, deleting `tempName` will delete what `name` is pointing to. Don't do it.

Moreover, using C++, why you don't use `std::string` instead of C-style strings and let the `std::string` to manage its memory.

---

<sub>*<sup>†</sup> Of course you can disobey C++ ways and have your own behaviours for operators. But it's not recommended.*</sub>

Comment: Note on the moreover, the use of `std::string` rather than manually managing `char *name;` cannot be oversold. With it, it is highly likely neither this custom assignment operator nor the unseen copy-ctor wouldn't even be necessary, as the compiler defaults for both would probably be sufficient.

Comment: @WhozCraig: That's true, it can avoid unnecessary complexity on writing copy-ctr.

Answer (score 1):

1. To avoid an unnecessary copy. Chaining would work even if you return a value, so it's not strictly necessary. Returning a reference is mainly to mimic assignment of native types where the compiler returns an l-value rather than an r-value. Even the compiler generated assignment operator returns a reference.
2. You delete the memory in the destructor.
3. If you delete and then return, the caller won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Question 1 :

In C++ (as in C) an assignement returns a value. In fact `a = b = c` is simply : `a = (b = c)` because `b = c` returns the new value of b.

That's the reason why to avoid breaking language semantics, the assignement operation **must** return a reference to the object after assignement.

#### Question 2 :

You **must** release memory before loosing access to the pointer. One simple way is to encapsulate to raw pointer in an object and do the delete in the destructor (of the encapsulating object). That's why `std::unique_ptr` is for. But in this use case, `tempname` has been affected to the `name` attribute of the object. Simply delete the `name` in `Contact` destructor.

#### Question 3 :

`this->name` seems to be a raw pointer that happens to point to newly allocated `tempname`. If you delete `tempname` before the return, `this->name` will point to freed memory => what it called a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 0):

### 1: Why that assignment operator return Reference Object

Chaining assignment is the syntax where you assign values to multiple holders at once like `a = b = c`. You can understand it this way: `b=c; a=b;` as it executes from right to left it stack. Chaining can be achieved by returning by value as well as by returning by reference. 
Now back to your question "why reference?". References are used for optimization. When you return by value a copy of the value is created and send back to the calling code. 
Consider the code below for better understanding:

`class A
{
    int _a;
public:
    void setA(int a){ _a = a; }
    A() :_a(0){}
    A operator=(const A&);// here we are returning by value 
    A& operator=(const A&);// here we are returning by reference. 
    //Both support chaining but using reference avoids unnecessary copy 
};`

---

### 2: I have created dynamic pointer tempName but I've not release the memory, so there is a memory leak. How I can resolve that. Or give me example if you have

You don't have to allocate memory with tempName, instead you can use 'name' itself. Refer to below code snippet:

`delete[ ] name;`

```
char* name = new char[ strlen( rhs. name ) + 1];
```

---

### 3: I have assigned tempName in name, so name is pointing to tempName if I delete tempName before the return, then what will happen.

Since in your code(which is not ideal) name and `tempName` are pointing to same memory location. Deleting `tempName` will cause a heap corruption for `name` which means when you will try to access `name` program will break.

---

I hope that helped. Comment for any further clarification.

Comment: Deleting `name` before accessing `rhs.name` invokes undefined behavior on self-assignment.